# All forms in Symfony 2 app erase their data before validating

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, production-environment

I have a small app running on Symfony 2.4, which works perfectly fine on my local setup.

But I deployed it on a shared-web hosting service (OVH), and lately, all the forms stopped working. Yes, even the symfony parameters configurator.

On each and every form, what happens is: the submission process goes fine, as much as I can see. In Firebug, I can see that each parameter of the POST request is correctly filled and sent to the right action. But after that, I get redirected back to the form, all fields are empty, and I get a validator warning above each required field saying "please fill up ". Which I did!

Even the hidden csrf_token seems to be erased. I used to think csrf_protection was the problem (because of the "invalid csrf token" warning), but I disabled it and it turns out it's just an effect of the fields being erased somehow.

Anyone knows how to investigate this?

Comment: Can you submit your action code?

Comment: Which one? It happens on every action, even `/app_dev.php/_configurator/step/0` (the symfony configurator) which I can assure I didn't touch. So I'm pretty sure all the data is deleted before it even reaches the controller action. Or during the `$request->get()` or something.

Comment: Have you checked if the server is suitable to run Symfony? see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Comment: This is what I am worried about... Since it's a shared hosting, it's pretty constraining. But obviously it worked in the first place after I deployed, I have user submissions in the database. So it has worked, but doesn't anymore.

Comment: What is the PHP version on your hosting?